# c++ support for last call optimization in template metaprogramming

Tags: c++

I am reading about C++ templates and would like to contrast two different implementations of a function which computes sum from 0 to N.

Unfortunately, I have problems and would like to address a few questions through examples:

Code for naive sum:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<int N>
struct Sum {
    // Copied the implementation idea from Scott Meyers book
    // "Effective C++". Is there a better way?
    enum { value = N + Sum<N - 1>::value };
};

template<>
struct Sum<0> {
    enum { value = 0 };
};

int main() {
    // Works well in this case, but gives compilation error, if
    // it's called with a larger value, such as 10000
    // (error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900").
    // How to improve the program properly, that it would
    // not give compile time error?
    printf("%d\n", Sum<100>::value);
}
```

Now my idea for an improvement is to use an accumulator:

```
template<int Acc, int N>
struct Sum {
    enum { value = Sum<Acc + N, N - 1>::value };
};

// Is that an appropriate way of writing the base case?
template<int Acc> 
struct Sum<Acc, 0> {
    enum { value = Acc };
};
```

However, when compiled with simple g++ on Ubuntu OS:

```
int main() {
    // Still gives the "depth exceeded" error.
    printf("%d\n", Sum<0, 1000>::value);
}
```

Hence, my main concern is:

**Does any modern c++ compiler support last call optimisation for
template metaprogramming? If yes, what is an appropriate way to write code for such optimisation?**

Comment: I guess it is out of the question just to use something as simple as `(N+1)N/2` -

Comment: With C++14 it seems to be much easier to use `constexpr` function. For this example, I think, even c++11 `constexpr` will be easy.

Comment: if you're talking about
printf("%d\n", Sum<100>::value);
Then it is not a typo, because the template uses only one argument in the first (naive) case

Comment: @StillLearning This is just an experimental example. Yes, (N + 1)N / 2 would work here, but there are many cases where using recursion could be a nice way to evaluate expressions, such as traversing trees, e.t.c.

Comment: @mercury0114 - Of cause, I just couldn't help laughing over the example. It is great at illustrating how little effort it takes in C++ to turn simple problems into complex solutions. I would call it a mistake if Scott Meyers book has that as an example - it should be possible to come up with an example where the solution made sense. Anyway - no offence meant by my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does any modern c++ compiler support last call optimisation for template metaprogramming? If yes, what is an appropriate way to write code for such optimisation?

No, and it wouldn't make sense.  Template instantiations are not function calls... *last/tail call optimisation* has no relevance here.  Unlike function calls, template instantiations are not transient with automatic variables to reclaim; rather, each template instantiation becomes a new type in the compiler's state.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of template metaprogramming is that all of these "calls" will be optimised out of your program; they are "executed" during the build.

That doesn't change the fact that there is an implementation-defined limit to the amount of recursion you can use during this process. This is the limit you've hit.

So, no, there's no "optimisation" to work around it.

Comment: But why couldn't there be such "optimisation", when LCO is widely used in many functional programming languages? C++ compilers do many other optimizations, which I image are much more complicated to implement than LCO, so why wouldn't it provide such relatively simple feature? Especially given that Template Meta programming is like a distinct programming language that is incorporated in C++.

Note: in the second case ideally I am not using any "recursion limit", it works with O(1) extra stack space.

Comment: @mercury0114: "Optimised" or not, your computer has to parse the code. It's as simple as that. This is a limit on how far it'll go doing that. Optimisations aren't a magical property of the universe that eliminates the need for computers to do work. At best it transforms the work into a different piece of work.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **incorporating LCO is not worth the trouble**.

Longer explanation:

C++ template meta programming is *Turing Complete*. In theory it would be possible to compute any computable function at compile time using **only** templates (if enough resources were given). LCO would make such computation more efficient.

That does not mean templates should be used for sophisticated computations. Run time is for that. C++ templates merely aid to avoid writing identical code.

In fact, doing complicated computation through templates is discouraged, because one has little compiler support. The preprocessor will only expand templated code into more code and that's it. No type checking, etc. is happening when processing templates.

So I think the designers of c++ have more interesting things to add in the language rather than optimise template meta programming. Maybe after 20 years we will have LCO support. Currently there is no.